# Auto sign on with Windows Authentication

Tags: windows, wcf, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am to be having a lot of problems, misinformation and confusion when attempting to find out the plausibility and viability of attempting this.

The requirement is for a remote client, accessing our website to be auto signed in with their Active Directory User account. 
We have the option to setup a WCF service (or something similar) on their remote server for authentication purposes. Which from my little understanding is how this problem will be tackled.

So, my question after a little background is this.

CAN this be done, and HOW can it be done?

Comment: What kind of authentication is the website currently using? Can you change that if needed?

Comment: Will the client's account be in your domain and recognized by AD?  If that is the case and you are hosting in IIS, just set the authentication scheme for the service to Windows Auth.  Otherwise, you may need to implement a custom username password validator.

Comment: @Tim The clients will be inside their own domain and recognised by AD, yes. And we are hosting on IIS.

Comment: @MvdD We can change our authentication methods yes. We are using Web Forms at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hosting a WCF service on their domain, I would look into installing [ADFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx) on their domain.

You can change your website to accept security tokens from ADFS using the [WS-Federation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb498017.aspx) protocol. You can use classes from the System.IdentityModel namespace for that. An example of how to implement this in ASP.NET can be found [here](http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/03/07/claims-based-authentication-in-net4-5-mvc4-with-c-external-authentication-with-ws-federation-part-1/).

An alternative would be to use Azure Active Directory as your identity provider and have your client sync accounts to their AAD directory (or federate between AAD and ADFS). An example can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation).